# Отключение панели Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Имеется панель `MMenu`,на которой находится кнопка `Exit`. По нажатию на `Exit` должна выводиться панель `CheckExit` (которая так же размещена на панели `MMenu`) (`CheckExit` представляет собой проверку выхода из программы,в виде 2 кнопок "Назад" и "Выход").

`CheckExit` небольшого размера, и не перекрывает полностью все элементы панели `MMenu`,что позволяет нажимать на кнопки панели `MMenu`, которые остались видны.

Вопрос - как отключить все элементы на панели `MMenu` (Кроме панели `CheckExit`, разумеется), чтобы пользователь во время проверки, мог работать только с элементами `CheckExit`и при этом, элементы панели `MMenu` должны оставаться видимыми?

Comment: Лучше приложите часть своего кода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, для всех элементов меню вызывайте метод `setEnabled(false);` в момент нажатия на Exit. И обратно `setEnabled(true);`, если нажато "Назад"